# Stack direction and buffer overflow

Tags: stack, buffer-overflow

In a downward growing stack, what's the rationale for stack variables to be written in an upward direction? For example, if I have char buf[200], say at memory address 0x400. When I write to this array, I will write from 0x400 to 0x600, which is toward previous stack frames. This makes the program vulnerable to buffer overflows that can take control over the program by overwriting return pointers, etc. So why not just write the array from 0x600 to 0x400?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter; when you try to write beyond 200 bytes, you are still trying to write to an address that does not belong to the array (out of bounds), hence buffer overflow.

Comment: i edited my question. when you write downwards, you can't overwrite return addresses, so it's harder for attackers to take control?

Comment: While you can't overwrite the current stack's own return address by doing so, you still cannot make any assumptions on what's adjacent to the array -- it could be a function pointer, it could be another stack frame for a subroutine your function is calling. For example, consider `memset(&buf, 300, 0);`.